# How to upgrade script file when Upgrading app for SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

I want to update only script file from sharepoint app without lost data from List.
I refer this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/06/13/upgrading-your-app-for-sharepoint/

but its not work..

Comment: How you upgrade your app?
Package your app and upgrade to app catalog instead of installing by Visual Studio.
https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-add-ins-update-process Regards,
Lee

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/81953)